# Is it ok to run 15k.6 and 15k.5 SAS disks in a SAN together?

Tags: hp, storage-area-network, sas

I have a SAN (HP MASA 2012) running seagate Cheetah 15k.6 drives. One has failed and I have a replacement drive that is the same except for it is a 15k.5 drive. Is this ok to run in the SAN? What are the repercussions, if any?

Comment: Sounds like a question you should direct to HP Support.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've chosen to run non-HP disks in that MSA, meaning it's not a supported configuration, is that right? if so then there's little real difference between those generations of disks, I can't promise they'll work, but it probably will. Obviously if I'm wrong and you are using HP supported disks then so long as they're a supported disk then HP will happily...well...support your array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work. But why not use the purpose-built part? Why aren't you replacing the disk using your HP contract. Those drives are warranteed for 3 years.